# Parametrize (as a subset of R5) the solution space of the system of equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I am just wondering how I would parametrize the system of equations from the augmented matrix

I know the following:

v = -2 - 4w -3z

w = 0

x = 0

y = 8 - 5z

z = 0

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & -2 & 0 & -3& -2\\ 0 & 0& 0& 1& 5 &8 \end{bmatrix}

Please note that the last two numbers are supposed to have a line.

|-2 

|8

Comment: Your matrix doesn’t correspond to the system of equations that you’ve written here. If you back-substitute for $w$, $x$ and $z$ into the other two equations, you’ll find that the solution is unique—there’s nothing to parameterize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your equations the matrix should be:
$$ A|\vec{b}=\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 4 &0 & 0 &3 \\
0 & 0 &0 &1&5 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1
\end{array} \right | \left. \begin{array}{c}
-2 \\
8  \\
0   \\
0  \\
0
\end{array}\right ) $$ with $$ A \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
v\\
w\\
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} = \vec{b}$$ 
In this case the only fitting solution would be $$\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
v\\
w\\
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
0\\
0\\
8\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $$
In case you misinterpreted the matrice, the parametrization will look as follows:
$$ A|\vec{b}=\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 4 &-2 & 0 &-3 \\
0 & 0 &0 &1&5 \\
\end{array} \right | \left. \begin{array}{c}
-2 \\
8  \\
\end{array}\right ) $$ We now use the Gaussian Elimination ([Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)) . Since the matrix is already in reduced row echolon form ([Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)), we can do the following:
We set every variable in a row as a free parameter $\lambda_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$ , except for one variable (usually the one with coefficient 1) :
$$ w=\lambda_{1}; x=\lambda_{2};z=\lambda_{3}$$
First row: $$v= -2 \,-4\lambda_{1}+2\lambda_{2}+3\lambda_{3} $$
Second row:  $$y= 8- 5\lambda_{3} $$
Now we can rewrite this in vectorform, which gives us the parametrization:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
v\\
w\\
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 \,-4\lambda_{1}+2\lambda_{2}+3\lambda_{3} \\
\lambda_{1}\\
\lambda_{2}\\
8- 5\lambda_{3}\\
\lambda_{3}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
0\\
0\\
8\\
0
\end{pmatrix} + \lambda_{1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-4\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{2} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{3} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
3\\
0\\
0\\
-5\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\\ $$

Comment: Thank you , your final conclusion is what I was looking for exactly!